# Javascript regex with dot or underscore for all letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to have a regular expression that checks if a string contains all letters, numbers, and underscores or dot.
Example Ok:

1. `adjh55_`
2. `jfgj..878`
3. `kjf56_..k`

Not ok:

1. `kjk88=--_`
2. `985469_)`
3. `lkd+_=`

Comment: @user3388695 Just to let you know `\w` is same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex,

```
^[\w.]+$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qJ9cY9/7)

Comment: This is bad solution. because rule  should not contain special characters except dot or underscore. I am using this 
(?=.*[0-9])([^\\p{L}])(?=.*[._]) but it's also not very good

Comment: it won't allow special chars other than _ or dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^[\w.]+$
```